# How to Keep Django Project Running After Putty Close?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, digital-ocean

i am new in django and i am uploading Django Project on digitalocean server first Time. My Upload is Successfull. i have Connected my digitalocean  server Using Putty.
when i run my Server ,it works Fine, but when i close Putty my Project Stopped Working .I have aplied following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
Hit Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + D in immediate succession. You will see the message [detached]
screen -r
screen -D -r
```

Howevver its not working.

How to keep running Django Project after closing Putty?

Comment: There is no need to repeat the question or appreciation for the person providing hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to launch screen in the first place.

Once installed, you can launch a new screen (it's a bit like a new "window") with:

```
screen -a
```

From there, you can launch the development server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Then, you detach from the screen (the new "window" in which python is now running) with CTRL + A, then D.  You can then disconnect Putty safely.

If you want to see the screen again, use this in Putty:

```
screen -r
```

Alternatively, you could use the `nohup` command instead of a screen.